# Can not read MMS on dual SIM phone

Tags: mms, bugs, lg-optimus-l5-2

A have two SIM card phone: LG E455 (Optimus L5 II Dual). Primary SIM card is full operation, secondary is receiving calls and SMS only. SIM cards are from different providers.

I received MMS message notification to the SIM2. Trying to open it I get the message "Switch default data network SIM card to retrieve MMS: Cancel, Settings". If I'd choose "Settings" I'd see that my default data network is SIM1 (SIM2 is not able to transfer data at all). So the message can not be loaded.

What can I do to go through this dump bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have data service at all on your secondary SIM, you can't download the SMS. Since the SIMs are from different carriers, the primary SIM can't connect to the other carrier's MMS service, and therefore the message can't be downloaded.

The only solution would be to replace your primary SIM with the secondary one, establish a data connection and download the MMS. Otherwise you can't download it.

Comment: That's a pity :( In my case secondary SIM card is limited not by the phone but by operator.

Comment: Couldn't you physically swap it into the primary SIM slot just until you get the MMS message?

Comment: It will not help, SIM2 is not able to transfer date at all :(